# An unhandled exception of type 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException' occurred in ConsoleApp3.dll Index was outside the bounds of the array

Tags: c#, visual-studio

The code has no errors and issues but when i run it an red cross appears besides the `Console.WriteLine(item[j]);` prompting `Index` was outside the bounds of the array

```cs
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp3{

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string[] arr = { "ABC", "BCD", "CBE", "DEF", "EFG", "FGH" };
            foreach (var item in arr)
            {
                if (item == "BCD")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("BCD found!");
                    int j = 3;
                    while (j >= 0)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(item[j]);
                        j--;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

yes you are doing it wrong. Because item (BCD) has length `3`. index starts from 0. so you can access maximum upto to 2.

```
Console.WriteLine(item[j]);
```

Comment: Perfect i changed the 3  to 2 and its fine now. Thank you

Comment: @user13731801, I am glad to hear that your question has been solved. You can [consider accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).